# ¿Puedo regenerar el árbol DOM con JQuery sin tener que refrescar la página?

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

Tengo una tabla que contiene elementos con *ID* pero cuando añado de forma dinámica una fila, esos nuevos elementos no son reconocidos por el árbol *DOM*.

Cuando cargo la pagina tengo esta estructura en la tabla:

```
<table id="tabla">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="v_1">Elemento 1</span></td>
      <td><span id="e_1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</tabla>
```

Desde *JQuery* agrego una nueva fila con:

```
$('#tabla tbody').append('<tr><td><span id="v_2">Elemento 2</span></td><td><span id="e_2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td></tr>');
```

... e inspecciono la página, y todo bien, me aparece así

```
<table id="tabla">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="v_1">Elemento 1</span></td>
      <td><span id="e_1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="v_2">Elemento 2</span></td>
      <td><span id="e_2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</tabla>
```

Pero los *ID* `v_2` y `e_2` son inaccesibles porque no están en el árbol *DOM*. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: ¿Qué quieres hacer con dichos elementos?

Comment: Cuál es tu método para acceder a esos `id`?

Comment: No tiene sentido "regenerar el arbol DOM". Si el `append` anduvo, entonces lo que hizo fue precisamente actualizar el DOM. Tu error tiene que estar en otro lado.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si será porque tienes la etiqueta `</tabla>` en vez de `</table>` pero a mí si que me deja acceder a esos ID. Como puedes comprobar en el ejemplo saco el texto que hay en el ID `v_2`.

Ejemplo:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#tabla tbody').append('<tr><td><span id="v_2">Elemento 2</span></td><td><span id="e_2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td></tr>');
    
    console.log($("#v_2").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="v_1">Elemento 1</span></td>
      <td><span id="e_1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para delegar eventos a elementos del `DOM` que fueron creados de manera dinámica, yo utilizaría la función `on()` de la siguiente forma:

```
$('tbody').on('click', 'span',function(){
  console.log("hice click en " + this.id);
})
```

1. Selecciono el padre que desde un inicio existió al iniciar la pagina `$('tbody')`
2. en el método `on()` le paso los parámetros `{click, focus, mouseenter, ...}, {selector donde se hará la función},{función a realizar}`

El selector tiene que ser una clase que todos los elementos contenga igual en este caso la `<span>`

Así todos los elementos generados tengan esa función que desees

[Referencia](http://www.arumeinformatica.es/blog/jquery-asociar-eventos-a-elementos-html-creados-dinamicamente/)

Ejemplo funcionando:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('#tabla tbody').append('<tr><td><span id="v_2">Elemento 2</span></td><td><span id="e_2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td></tr>');
})

$('tbody').on('click', 'span',function(){
  console.log("hice click en " + this.id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabla">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="v_1">Elemento 1</span></td>
      <td><span id="e_1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
<!-- suponiendo que agregas la columna por X función o alguna acción-->
<button>hola</button>
```